# Preg_match match words between start and end

Tags: php, preg-match

I hate preg_match syntax!

[file.txt]
Source:

```
  sth = s("Would you like to go to the cinema "+
                               "With me?");
        }
        else if (something)
        {
            sth = s("Would you like to go to the cinema "+
                               "With me?");
        } else {
sth = s("Sure, no problem");
}
```

PHP:

```
$file = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$file = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $file);
preg_match_all("/s\(\"(.*) /", $file, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

This shows too much words because i have "start point" and no end of pattern. But I dont know, how I can create preg with ending delimeter like this:

`preg_match("/ [s(" .... ")] /")`

I want draw from source:

```
"Would you like to go to the cinema With me?" 
"Would you like to go to the cinema With me?" 
"Sure, no problem"
```

Please help me with create pattern.

Comment: Sorry, but that is _not_ php code.

Comment: So where is your php code then? Or do you just want someone else to do your work for you?

Comment: i Have only this:
$file = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$file = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $file);
preg_match_all("/t\(\"(.*) /", $file, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
This shows too much words.
But i dont know how i can create preg like this:
preg_match("/ [s(" .... ")] /")

Comment: Sorry, please add additional information to the question above. Not in a comment here where it is unreadable. There is an `edit` button below the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this,

`$regex = "/s\\(\\\"(.*?)\\\"\\);/s";`

and replace `+` and `"` from the output

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sS2vK8/1)